# elementary question regarding conditional probability

Tags: probability, contest-math, conditional-probability

**question:**

[image]

$a)\dfrac{1}{14}$

$b)\dfrac{13}{14}$

$c)\dfrac{1}{5}$

$d)\dfrac{2}{7}$

**my attempt:**

for probability of result to  be correct both  A and B have to solve wrong and make mistake or both have to solve right  without making mistake

from question one can infer probability of making no mistake is  $\dfrac{1000}{1001}$ and making mistake is $\dfrac{1}{1001}$

after that i don't know how to proceed further should i use bye's theoram here

or use probability tree method. i'm confused please help and if possible please solve by tree method .
thanks in advance .

Comment: Are you sure you've stated the problem correctly? Is it from a book? If so, which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A$ be the event that student $A$ answers the question correctly; let $B$ be the event that student $B$ answers the question correctly; and let $C$ be the event that $A$ and $B$ coincidentally obtain the same wrong answer.  We are given 
\begin{align*}
\Pr(A) & = \frac{1}{8}\\
\Pr(B) & = \frac{1}{12}
\end{align*}
from which we can determine that 
\begin{align*}
\Pr(A^C) & = 1 - \frac{1}{8} = \frac{7}{8}\\
\Pr(B^C) & = 1 - \frac{1}{12} = \frac{11}{12}
\end{align*}
We are also given that the odds against $A$ and $B$ obtaining the same wrong answer are $1000:1$, which means that 
$$\Pr(C) = \frac{1}{1000 + 1} = \frac{1}{1001}$$
The probability that $A$ and $B$ obtain the correct result given that they obtain the same answer is
$$\frac{\Pr(A \cap B)}{\Pr(A \cap B) + \Pr(A^C \cap B^C)\Pr(C)}$$
Assuming the probability that student $A$ solves the problem correctly is independent of the probability that student $B$ solves the problem correctly, we obtain
\begin{align*}
\frac{\Pr(A \cap B)}{\Pr(A \cap B) + \Pr(A^C \cap B^C)\Pr(C)} & = \frac{\Pr(A)\Pr(B)}{\Pr(A)\Pr(B) + \Pr(A^C)\Pr(B^C)\Pr(C)}\\
& = \frac{\frac{1}{8} \cdot \frac{1}{12}}{\frac{1}{8} \cdot \frac{1}{12} + \frac{7}{8} \cdot \frac{11}{12} \cdot \frac{1}{1001}}\\
& = \frac{\frac{1}{96}}{\frac{1}{96} + \frac{77}{96096}}\\
& = \frac{1}{1 + \frac{77}{1001}}\\
& = \frac{1}{\frac{1078}{1001}}\\
& = \frac{1001}{1078}\\
& = \frac{13}{14}
\end{align*}

Comment: thanks a lot . very nicely done .... :)